# How to create tabbed page in Xamarin.Forms similar to that of Facebook app

Tags: c#, tabbar, navigationbar, xamarin.forms

I am working with **Xamarin.Forms** and I would like to create a navigation method similar to that of the Facebook app and also other newer versions of different apps. Here are two pictures, one of Facebook app on **Android** and the other is of KakaoTalk, also on **Android**.

[image: Facebook app on Android]

[image: KakaoTalk app on Android]

I've tried several different ways to implement this. For example I wrapped the MainPage (*TabbedPage*) inside a *NavigationPage*. I also tried wrapping the MainPage (*ContentPage*) inside a *NavigationPage* then calling

```
PushAsync(new TabbedPage());
```

inside the MainPage via the `Navigation` property. I also tried wrapping the children of the MainPage (*TabbedPage*) inside separate *NavigationPage*s. None of these attempts resulted in the desired effect.

I would like the following to happen. When a user taps on a *Button* or something that navigates to another page I'd like a *ContentPage* to pop in front of everything (tab bar included) except for the *Navigation bar* (or Action Bar). Obviously this happens via the `PushAsync()` method which also results in a small back arrow appearing in the Nav bar. My understanding is that a `PushAsync()` call pushes the chosen page onto the navigation stack provided by the *NavigationPage*. Therefore if a *TabbedPage* is wrapped inside a *NavigationPage* a new *ContentPage* would not be able to pop in front of the tabs like in the two applications mentioned above.

This, plus the fact that the tab bars of said apps don't get inside the *ActionBar* (in Android) in landscape mode leads me to believe that what I'm trying to achieve is best done not using *TabbedPage* but something that acts like a tab bar, e.g. a horizontal stack of *Buttons* perhaps.

Has anyone implemented this correctly and in an elegant way using Xamarin.Forms? So again, I would like to make this tab like navigation with the tabs staying underneath the *ActionBar* in landscape mode and a new Page appearing in front of the tabs (hiding them) when pushed onto the navigation stack. Do you think this can be done with *Custom Renderer*s? Of course in **iOS** these are done with tabs but in Android I'm not sure.

What I would like is not necessarily code examples, but a best practice on this issue. So again, this is in Xamarin.Forms with a common **PCL** project and an Android and iOS project. Thank you in advance for your answers and advices!

P.S.: I've obviously searched this site before (Google as well) but I've found no real articles on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have used ToolbarItems order=primary for navigation bar menu button and ToolbarItems order=secondary for tab bar on top.I have PCL the code written is in XAML. :)

http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=232

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that a PushAsync() call pushes the chosen page onto the navigation stack provided by the NavigationPage. Therefore if a TabbedPage is wrapped inside a NavigationPage a new ContentPage would not be able to pop in front of the tabs like in the two applications mentioned above.

This is not true actually. According to [Xamarin API Doc](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aXamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Navigation), the `Navigation` property is context-aware, i.e. it will find all its parents until there is a `NavigationPage`.

In Android, only **one** `NavigationPage` is allowed and therefore even you call `PushAsync()` inside the `TabbedPage`, it will still push via your wrapping `NavigationPage`.

Comment: Yeah, well, this is true :D Thank you for this. Actually, I've found the answer since. I use a ViewPager in Android and tabs in iOS. I don't think there is a common code solution for this problem that behaves the way I wanted it.

Comment: @GáborBirkás Can you post the code of the solution you found as the official answer to the question? Many people like me have the same problem, and your solution seems interesting. Is it a custom renderer? Can you post it here or as a basic github sample project?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom controller using the grid. it will remove the hassle of writing custom renderers.